# Issue with Java Loop Conditions

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, math, while-loop

I am working on Java loops for an assignment. I had to write a loop that starts with three countries populations, raises/lowers each one until one country is lower than the other two, and prints the populations, and the years it took to reach that result.

I am using two conditions with the correct code, but when the conditions are correct, they aren't acting correctly. The loop has to run until the Mexican and Japanese populations are higher than the USA population, so this is what I am working with:

If I use this condition - mexpop > usapop && jappop > usapop the loop doesn't run because USA is already higher than Mexico and Japan (315,000,000 versus 121,000,000 and 127,000,000).

If I use this condition - mexpop < usapop && jappop < usapop, the loop runs but it doesn't display the proper results since the USA pop is supposed to be lower than Mexico and Japan.

This last option I tried is this: usapop < mexpop && usapop < jappop and if I am right, this one should work because usapop (315,000,000) is not greater than either mexpop or jappop (121,000,000 and 127,000,000).

The expected output should be obvious, but this is what I am getting:

The Mexican population is 273,286,490. The United States population is 278,014,339. The Japanese population is 278,115,163. This change took 78 year(s).

I think Japan pop is higher out of sheer luck, but it doesn't seem to be meeting both conditions even though I am using the logical AND operator.

````
/* Import Java utilities required for the program. */
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

class Population_for {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

   /** Declare variables that will be used in the program. **/
   double usapop, mexpop, jappop;
   int years;

   /** This is the start of the for loop.
     * The first line declares the variables (mexpop, usapop, jappop), the second line declares the conditions (mexpop less than**/
   for(mexpop=121000000, usapop=315000000, jappop=127000000, years=1; mexpop < usapop && jappop < usapop; years++){
      mexpop = mexpop * 1.0105;
      usapop = usapop * 0.9984;
      jappop = jappop * 1.0101;
      DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###");
      System.out.println("The Mexican population is "+(df.format(mexpop))+". The United States population is "+(df.format(usapop))+". The Japanese population is "+(df.format(jappop))+". This change took "+years+" year(s).");
      System.out.println("");
   }
   }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you've made the unfortunate mistake of applying logic that would be correct if it were used in an `if` statement to the `for` loop. The `for` loop runs whilst the condition is true.

When you get to the point where the Japanese population is > the USA population, `mex < use && japan < usa` is no longer true (as one is false). You therefore need to use logical or (`||`) so that the loop keeps running until they're both true.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've misunderstood how the logical `and` and `or` operate.
A `and` statement needs both sides to be true to evaluate to true, an or statement needs either side to be true to evaluate to true to be true.

So if you want your for-loop to stop when both mexpop and jappop is bigger then usapop you could do that with `or`.

But even better would be to write a negated version of what you're actually testing, so if you want your for-loop to loop until usa is no longer bigger than one of the other two you could write:

```
!(mex>usa && jap>use)
```

which would be true until both mex and jap were larger than usa.